# How to set width and height of mask-image in css?

Tags: css, css-mask

I have a div with image using  `-webkit-mask-image` CSS
but i can't set width and height for this -webkit-mask-image like css background image...

```css
.img {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}

.img {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/6Bkc0h8/gZvK4.png');
          mask-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/6Bkc0h8/gZvK4.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider `mask-size` which behave like `background-size`. There is also a property for the position and the repeat:

```css
.img {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}

.img {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/6Bkc0h8/gZvK4.png');
  -webkit-mask-size:contain; /* OR cover OR fixed values */
  
  -webkit-mask-position:center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  mask-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/6Bkc0h8/gZvK4.png');
  mask-size:contain; /* OR cover OR fixed values */
  
  mask-position:center;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>

<div class="img" style="height:60px;"></div>
```

Reference: https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#positioned-masks

Comment: great... and also how to set width and height a unique size.? i mean if i set 30px width height also must be reduce depends on width

Comment: @mans you are probably looking for `-webkit-mask-size: contain;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mask-size, like so:

```
mask-size: 50px 50px;
```

The first value is width, the second is height.

More information on these properties here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-size